# Multicast Encryption

Tags: java, security, encryption, integrity, confidentiality

I'm developing a java project that uses messages as a way of communication between entities in a delivery chain.

These messages were encrypted (RSA) by one entity and then decrypted by the next one in the chain. Is it possible to implement Multicast/Broadcast encryption in java so that one entity will encrypt it and then all of them in the chain can decrypt it?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, if they all know the decryption key. This is a key distribution problem, not really a programming problem.

Comment: Agreed, you are mixing protocol design & specification with the programming language. Of course it is useful if the default Java feature set allows for the cryptographic functions to be easily implemented, but otherwise the two should be separate. Why not remove the Java part and ask for multipart encryption using RSA on https://security.stackexchange.com?